# WCF async call raises exception which goes to the Unhandled Exception handler - none of my code in the callstack

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, windows-phone-7

I am making a WCF call to ASP.NET from Windows Phone (7.0, 7.1 SDK). In some cases (I could not make this happen on the emulator or any of my devices), the unhandled exception handler fires for an exception that happens in one of these calls (clarification - this is all on the client - not on the server). I see two occurrances of this (they happen quite a bit). I have never had this issue before (not on older versions, and not on other apps that use the same WCF proxy code).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how? And what I can do to work around it?

The first callstack this is happening on is:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 75 bytes of the response were: 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EndGetResponse>b__1(Object sendState)    at    
System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)    at    
System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at    
System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at    
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FastInvoke>b__3()    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)    at    
System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at    
System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at    
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at    
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)    at    
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)    at    
System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)    at    
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)     at    
System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)    at    
System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)    at    
System.Threading.Timer.ring()     at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.ProcessResponse(HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
```

The second callback this is happening on is:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at    
http://MyServer.com/Fail/FailService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EndGetResponse>b__1(Object sendState)    at    
System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)    at    
System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at    
System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at    
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FastInvoke>b__3()    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at    
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)    at    
System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at    
System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at    
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at    
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)    at    
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)    at    
System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)    at    
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)     at    
System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)    at    
System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)    at    
System.Threading.Timer.ring()     at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)    at    
System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)    at    
System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)    at    
System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your web server/service may be crashing due to possibly unhandled exceptions. I would checked the event logs on the web server to see if there are cases where IIS is reporting crashes.

**Update for clarified question**

As I understand the question now, the problem is that if the web service is down, the WCF service is raising an exception that can only be caught in the unhandled exception handler.

I have never run across this behavior, but I understand why it is happening and have a possible solution. The WCF service request is fired asynchronously, so the actual connection and processing occur in a thread, which you can see in your call stack.

If you have hooked the asynchronous method's completion event, the exception should be passed in the parameters to that event handler rather than being thrown. I believe that the exception will only be thrown if there isn't a handler because the framework doesn't know what else to do with the exception.

Comment: That's not the issue (the server was actually down - not throwing exceptions) - the problem is that the **client** has an unhandled exception in it which cannot be caught anywhere but the unhandled exception handler - that's not how this should work.

Comment: Clarified the question. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Updated answer with additional info

Comment: I am hooking the completion event :(